# Selenide- different between open() & navigate & get

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

what are the differences between the following:

```
open(url); // this is from Selenide
```

&

```
 driver.navigate().to(url); //this is from selenium
```

&

```
driver.get(url); //this is from selenium
```

Comment: I don't know about selenide. For get and navigate refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664808/difference-between-webdriver-get-and-webdriver-navigate

Answer (score 3):

There is no big difference. `open(url)` is a synonym for `driver.navigate().to(url);`

Also, method `open(url)` supports relative urls. So you can set base url once and use relative urls all over your tests:

```
public void setUp() {
  Configuration.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8888";
}

@Test
public void test1() {
  open("/payments/index");
  ...
}
```