# How to make asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I am using mocha for testing.

With zombie.js, one can navigate to a webpage asynchronously like:

```
browser.visit(referrer, function(){
        browser.clickLink('.myLinkClass', function(){ 
            assert(browser.field('referrer').value === referrer);
            done();
        });
    });
```

But with selenium, you do:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```

The documentation does not mention any asynchronous callback that you can pass when the page is loaded. Is this feature absent ?

Comment: Does `webdriver.execute_async_script` not do that?

Comment: This SO post seems to address loading pages with ajax when using `.get` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664808/difference-between-webdriver-get-and-webdriver-navigate

Comment: @Fran that post describes the differences between get and navigate. It doesn't talk about ensuring that the page is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: check the answer. It states that it recommends the use of `waits` if you use `get` on an ajax heavy page. `...If you need to ensure such pages are fully loaded then you can use waits`

Comment: There is a difference between how both libraries are implemented. When you do `driver.get('http://www.google.com');` it schedules the operation in a queue. Read this article for more details http://www.assertselenium.com/selenium/promise-manager-in-webdriverjs/