# Firefox starts but url is cannot open using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

after run this program the Mozilla are automatically open and I login to proxy authentication but the url is not settled anybody can help thanks

```
 public class SimpleSelenium {
   WebDriver driver = null;
   String url = "http://www.google.com";



public static void main(String args[]) {


    SimpleSelenium ss = new SimpleSelenium();
    ss.openBrowser();
    ss.getPage();
    ss.quitPage();
}

private void openBrowser() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();


}

private void quitPage() {
    driver.quit();

}

private void getPage() {
    driver.get(url);  

  }

  }
```

Comment: is there needed to be quitpage immediately after getpage??

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method. It explained here [Difference between webdriver.get() and webdriver.navigate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664808/difference-between-webdriver-get-and-webdriver-navigate)

Try `driver.get("http://google.co.in");`

Comment: I copied your new, edited code and it works just fine. The only thing I changed was .exe path. I'm using Maven and there is resources folder `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");`. Maybe it will work?

Comment: what is your version of selenium jar and Mozilla?

Comment: Firefox 55.0.3. Selenium and firefox driver are at 3.4.0