# What is the difference between setting window size using Options and setting window size using set_window_size method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for setting window size in selenium.
I found this solution [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python)

```
rom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', service_args=["--log-path=./Logs/DubiousDan.log"])
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
print(driver.get_window_size())
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
size = driver.get_window_size()
print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
driver.quit()
```

Is there any difference in doing

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
```

or doing

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

I commented out the headless option in my windows machine and checked the code.
With `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`, I see windows size changes on browser.
But with `options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080")`, I don't see any change
Is `options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080")` only for headless mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the driver window size with
`driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`
and doing that with the use of `Options`
`options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`
Seems to be the same.
It's like
`driver.get(url)`
And
`driver.navigate().to(url)`
*WebDriver* methods that are doing [exactly the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665218/3485434) and actually are synonyms.
The only difference I can notice between setting the driver window size by
`driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)` vs `options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`
Is that setting / changing the driver window size by
`driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`
can be performed anywhere in your code, even several times, while setting the driver window size with
`options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")`
Can be performed only once, before creating the driver instance with
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=the_path`)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code:

1. `set_window_size`

**Code:**

```
def set_window_size(self, width, height, windowHandle='current'):
    """
    Sets the width and height of the current window. (window.resizeTo)

    :Args:
     - width: the width in pixels to set the window to
     - height: the height in pixels to set the window to

    :Usage:
        driver.set_window_size(800,600)
    """
    if self.w3c:
        if windowHandle != 'current':
            warnings.warn("Only 'current' window is supported for W3C compatibile browsers.")
        self.set_window_rect(width=int(width), height=int(height))
    else:
        self.execute(Command.SET_WINDOW_SIZE, {
            'width': int(width),
            'height': int(height),
            'windowHandle': windowHandle})
```

It is explicitly mentioned that it set

> width and height of the current window

takes two args:

```
- width: the width in pixels to set the window to
- height: the height in pixels to set the window to
```

2. `add_argument`

**Code:**

```
def add_argument(self, argument):
    """
    Adds an argument to the list

    :Args:
     - Sets the arguments
    """
    if argument:
        self._arguments.append(argument)
    else:
        raise ValueError("argument can not be null")
```

Now coming to your question:

> I commented out the headless option in my windows machine and checked
> the code. With driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080), I see windows size
> changes on browser. But with options.add_argument("window-size=1920,
> 1080"), I don't see any change Is
> options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080") only for headless mode?

With `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`, I see windows size
changes on browser - this is expected.

`options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080")`, I don't see any change Is
`options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080")` only for headless mode? - No, it ideally should have launched in 1920 and 1080 pixel. `add_argument` just add one `arg` to the **list**. doing `options.add_argument("--headless")` is optional.

Comment: ok, then it's not about headless mode.

Comment: correct! it's optional.

Comment: options.add_argument("window-size=1920, 1080") is this browser dependent?

Comment: what do you mean by browser dependent?